# Vb6 UI Automated Testing tools?

Tags: unit-testing, vb6, automation

What vb6 UI automated testing tools are available?

Additionally, would you rate the tools listed from 1-10, where ten means that its the most amazing tool ever and one means that its almost not worth listing.

Comment: Out of interest, what did you end up using, and how did it turn out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth looking at some of the other questions about automatic UI testing. I don't think there's anything particularly special about testing a VB6 UI.

- [Have you created a sustainable and successful test suite using UI automation on your Windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249041/is-there-anyone-who-successfully-implement-ui-test-automation-regime-using-micros)
- [User interface testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41601/user-interface-testing)

Comment: Hi, the first link is broken. if you could find the link, It would help me. Thanks!

Comment: It was a link to a StackOverflow question that unfortunately has been deleted. I just edited the link out of my answer. Sorry!